# ion-nav-view not working when trying to transition to new template

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to figure out how to transition from one url to another using ion-nav-view. Visual Studio compiles the code and doesnt throw any errors when trying to load the templates/events.html in the  tab. Any suggestions are welcome

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>SlidingTransitionwithAPI</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ionic-ion-swipe-cards/ionic.swipecards.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-ion-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="starter" no-scroll>
    <ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers',            'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards', 'ui.router'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
});
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
// Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
// Set up the various states which the app can be in.
// Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
$stateProvider

 .state('FindEvents', {
     url: '/findEvents',
     templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
     controller: 'EventsCtrl'
 })

.state('favorites', {
    url: '/favorites',
    templateUrl: 'templates/favorites.html',
    controller: 'FavoritesCtrl'
})


// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/findEvents');

});
```

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.directive('noScroll', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $element.on('touchmove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

})

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
var cardTypes = [
    { image: './images/event1.jpeg', title: 'New Apple Release' },
    { image: './images/event2.jpeg', title: 'Digital Conference' },
    { image: './images/event3.jpg', title: 'Skyline Sessions' },
    { image: './images/event4.jpg', title: 'Secret Rooftop Party' },
    { image: './images/event5.jpeg', title: 'Smoking Lights' },
    { image: './images/event6.jpg', title: 'Antibes Color Run' },
    { image: './images/event7.jpg', title: 'Tomorrowland' },
    { image: './images/event8.jpeg', title: 'Steve Aoki Lighting Up Town' },
    { image: './images/event9.jpeg', title: 'Nice Yacht Party' },
    { image: './images/event10.jpg', title: 'Night Pool Party' },

];

$scope.cards = [];

$scope.addCard = function () {
    for (var p = 0; p < 10; p++) {

        var newCard = cardTypes[p];
        newCard.id = Math.random();
        $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
    }
}

$scope.addCard();

$scope.cardDestroyed = function (index) {
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.cardSwipedLeft = function (index) {
    console.log('Left swipe');
}

$scope.cardSwipedRight = function (index) {
    console.log('Right swipe');
}

$scope.cardDestroyed = function (index) {
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('Card removed');
}

//Transitioning between states
$scope.Favorites = function () {

    $state.go('favorites');
}
});
```

events.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Time 'N Joy '" ng-controller="EventsCtrl">

<ion-content ng-app="starter" >
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
            <button class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
            <div class="h1 title" font="6" color="white">Event Finder</div>
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="Favorites()">
                <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <td-cards>
            <td-card id="td-card" ng-repeat="card in cards" on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)"
                     on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)" on-swipe-  right="cardSwipedRight($index)"
                     on-partial-swipe="cardPartialSwipe(amt)">
                <div class="title">
                    {{card.title}}
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <div class="no-text overlayBox"><div class="noBox boxed">Trash</div></div>
                    <img ng-src="{{card.image}}">
                    <div class="yes-text overlayBox"><div class="yesBox     boxed" id="centerMe">Save</div></div>
                </div>
            </td-card>
        </td-cards>
    </ion-pane>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It is probably something very straigh forward but I have gone through countless examples and documents but cant find the error.

Comment: Could you please provide more details what you mean by "not working". Is for example the back button not displayed or does the transition animation not work?

Comment: The emulator screen is blank therefore I take it that the ion-nav-view was not correctly configured @albert